# Zsh Package Suggestion

Tags: aptitude, zsh

I've just migrated to Zsh from Bash, but I have a bit of a problem in it. In bash on an Ubuntu system, when I type the name of a command which does not exist, Bash searches the apt database for a matching command name and prints out the package names that provide that command. It's a really useful feature, so I was wondering if something like that could be implemented in Zsh using a script or something?

Here's an example:

```
$>xmms2
The program 'xmms2' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install xmms2-client-cli
```

Or if the command is not an exact match:

```
$>xmms
No command 'xmms' found, did you mean:
Command 'lmms' from package 'lmms' (universe)
Command 'xmms2' from package 'xmms2-client-cli' (universe)
Command 'xmds' from package 'xmds' (universe)
Command 'xdms' from package 'xdms' (universe)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I've found the answer!
First you'll need to install a package named "command-not-found" (dunno about other distro's but in Ubuntu it's in the repositories).

```
sudo apt-get install command-not-found
```

And then you will need to edit your .zshrc and then source in the file /etc/zsh_command_not_found

```
source /etc/zsh_command_not_found
```

Comment: Just one minor detail. I get an error, say `zsh: command not found: gnug`, prior to the desired output. How do I get rid of that?